# How to see if Realm ObjectId equals String (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, realm, objectid, mongodb-realm

I'm using MongoDB's Realm and trying to see if an ObjectId is equal to a string with the same characters. I've tried casting the ObjectId to a string and vice versa, but No matter what I try, it doesn't see them as equal even though the values are the EXACT same and they look the same when I log them. Please help lol

Comment: Show how you are doing it

Answer (score 0):

ObjectId's can directly be used in comparisons with other ObjectId's - meaning there are <, >, <=, =>.

Also, the string representation of an ObjectId can be retrieved as

```
ObjectId.toString()
```

which returns the JavaScript representation in the form of a string literal "ObjectId(...)".

Given this

```
ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea").str
```

would evaluate to

```
507f191e810c19729de860ea
```